# How to prevent Add to home screen pwa from prompting again on www version of the site?

Tags: javascript, json, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am able to get Add to home screen popup on my website example.com but when I open my website with www.example.com, I again get the popup and on clicking on add, it adds the wpa again in the home screen.

How can I prevent this from happening as its useless to have two wpa icons of the same website?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could add some JavaScript code to remove the following tag whenever the user visits the `www`site.

`<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`

Example:

```
if (window.location.host.startsWith('www.') {
    const manifestLink = document.querySelector("link[rel='manifest']")
    manifestLink.parentNode.removeChild(manifestLink)
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this will make the www subdomain not suggest a pwa install at all?

Comment: That's right. Then I guess the best option is to follow @erndob 's suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Easiest option is to simply redirect www calls to non-www calls. So the users never actually stay in that different subdomain.

If for some reason you can't do that, on install of the PWA you could save a cross subdomain cookie just to have a "flag" set that the user installed the PWA. Then, in your code you listen to `beforeinstallprompt`event, and do not prompt the install if the cookie exists.